# Как получить текст из php посредством ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Всем привет, дорогие программисты. Передо-мной стоит такая задача, мне нужно получить из файла ajax.php последнюю строчку которая выводится в цикле, и подгрузить ее автоматически в блок c селектором #groupConsole,
как мне это реализовать?

Вот сам ajax.php:

```
$ch = file("ftp://{$config[ftpUser]}:{$config[ftpPass]}@{$config[host]}/logs/latest.log");

if (isset($_GET['q'])):
    if ($_POST['q'] == '1'):

        for ($c = 0; $c < count($ch); $c++) {   
           $logConsole = echo $ch[$c]."<br />";
        }
    endif;
endif;
```

А вот ajax.php:

```
function SendGet() {
    //отправляю GET запрос и получаю ответ
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',                        //тип запроса: get,post либо head
        url: 'ajax.php',                    //url адрес файла обработчика
        data: { 'q':'1' },                  //параметры запроса
        response: 'text',                   //тип возвращаемого ответа text либо xml
        success:function (data) {           //возвращаемый результат от сервера 
            $('#groupConsole').html(responce);
        }
    });
}
```

Строго не судите, ведь я еще новичок :ССС

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Как мне получить именно последнюю строчку из цикла в PHP?

Comment: последнюю? дык `echo $ch[count($ch) - 1]` и никакие циклы не нужны....

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня все динамически, то бишь текст обновляется, и мне нужно выводить каждый раз новую строку....

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы выводите пользователю страницу с каким-то содержимым, в которой есть блок с селектором #groupConsole, и Ваш скрипт с AJAX запросом. Таким образом, но момент загрузки страницы весь контент, который есть в файле логов (насколько я понял из php скрипта) уже загружен.

Далее, вы хотите добавлять последнюю строку из логов на Вашу страницу динамически, то есть через какой-то интервал времени или по какому-то событию.

Как Вам уже ответил Алексей Шиманский в комментариях, при запросе через AJAX Вам нужно получить только последнюю строку из файла логов и добавить ее в нужное место. А для того, чтобы динамически добавлять новые строки, которые появляются в файле, Вам нужно периодически повторять Ваш ajax-запрос. Например, с помощью функции SetInterval или SetTimeout (не силен в ajax-запросах, по-этому не могу привести нормальный рабочий код).

Тут специфика работы клиент-серверных технологий - клиент спросил, сервер ответил. Пока клиент не спрашивает, сервер не отвечает. И еще один момент, сервер, после выполнения запроса напрочь забывает все, что он передавал клиенту, и, если специально не сообщить, то он не знает, что есть у клиента. Так что если Вы хотите чтобы сервер сообщал только те строки, которых нет у клиента, то вам нужно или через запрос передавать информацию о том, что у клиента уже есть, или использовать сессии и т.д.

Продолжение.

Я, как и Вы, только изучаю веб-разработку, так что мой код далек от полноценного решения, но в качестве примера мой код может подойти.

Код index.php

```
<?php
$ch = file('logs.txt');
for ($i = 0, $l = count($ch) - 1; $i < $l; ++$i) {
    $result .= '<div>' . $ch[$i] . '</div>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test page</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="groupConsole">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function SendGet() {
    //отправляю GET запрос и получаю ответ
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',                        //тип запроса: get,post либо head
        url: 'ajax.php',                    //url адрес файла обработчика
        data: { 'q':'1' },                  //параметры запроса
        response: 'text',                   //тип возвращаемого ответа text либо xml
        success:function (data) {           //возвращаемый результат от сервера
            $('#groupConsole').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setTimeout(SendGet, 3000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код ajax.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/txt; charset=UTF-8");
$ch = file('logs.txt');
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  if ($_GET['q'] == 1) {
    echo '<div>' . trim($ch[count($ch) - 1]) . '</div>';
  }
}
?>
```

При загрузке страницы в блок #groupConsole добавляется три первых строки из файла logs.txt (всего в нем 4 строки), далее, через 3 секунды происходит AJAX-запрос и возвращаемые данные добавляются в качестве нового блока div внутрь блока #groupConsole.

Comment: Я это уже понял, но как же мне получить эту самую строку на AJAX и вывести ее в блок пользователю?